# Vibration Detection Using Apple Watch

Tags: swift, apple-watch, vibration

Is it possible to detect the intensity of vibration using Apple Watch?

Eg:- Someone tries to play cricket wearing AppleWatch. Is it possible to detect what type of shot is being played with the help of AppleWatch? Is the shot is Good or Very Good or Poor?

Have tried using CoreMotion Framework but didn't find any property to determine the Vibration through AppleWatch.

Comment: Vibration isn't going to help much for detecting the right movement. it has gyrosensors and other things available for detecting movement. Apple use it themselves for fall detection and workout detection. you would need to do what Apple done with fall detection. monitor the sensor data whilst doing the activity to try and learn patterns of movement that match up with each 'type of shot'. Far too much work to explain fully here. CoreML may definitely help too

Answer (score 0):

You can detect motion of the watch (in workout mode) with [Core Motion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion). I suspect, however, that detecting the "type of shot" from the accelerometer data is the real challenge here… Apple's [SwingWatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SwingWatch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017286-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) example may be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had even gone through Apple's SwingWatch SourceCode. Only the forehand and the backhand count was determined but couldn't find other hand movements like left or right and the velocity of the hand movements as well.

Comment: @AmitPalo Yes, you need to implement the detection by using the data in `CMDeviceMotion`, like they do with the swing count in the example. So basically the answer to your question is: yes, you can detect it in the sense that the data is available, but there is no built-in data analysis for your specific use case.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would start with the plain swing detection, then proceed to try to detect the point of impact by watching for sudden changes during a swing, and then look at the values (both delta and absolute) around the impact point of different "types" of strikes to see if any distinguishing patterns emerge.